# tic tac toe reduce runtime to O(N)

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

In this [great book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098478280X), we're asked to design an algorithm to figure out if someone has won in a game of tic-tac-toe.
The following solution is given, after which the author said:

> Note that the runtime could be reduced to O(N) with the addition of
>   row and column count arrays (and two sums for the diagonals)

I tried hard, but I couldn't figure out the meaning of that remark. How are these arrays and sums added ? Thanks !

```
enum Piece { Empty, Red, Blue };
enum Check { Row, Column, Diagonal, ReverseDiagonal }

Piece getIthColor(Piece[][] board, int index, int var, Check check) {
  if (check == Check.Row) return board[index][var];
  else if (check == Check.Column) return board[var][index];
  else if (check == Check.Diagonal) return board[var][var];
  else if (check == Check.ReverseDiagonal)      
    return board[board.length - 1 - var][var];      

  return Piece.Empty;
}

Piece getWinner(Piece[][] board, int fixed_index, Check check) {    
  Piece color = getIthColor(board, fixed_index, 0, check);
  if (color == Piece.Empty) return Piece.Empty;
  for (int var = 1; var < board.length; var++) {
    if (color != getIthColor(board, fixed_index, var, check)) {
      return Piece.Empty;
    }
  } 
  return color;
}

Piece hasWon(Piece[][] board) {
  int N = board.length;
  Piece winner = Piece.Empty;

  // Check rows and columns
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

    winner = getWinner(board, i, Check.Row);
    if (winner != Piece.Empty) {
      return winner;
    }       

    winner = getWinner(board, i, Check.Column);     
    if (winner != Piece.Empty) {
      return winner;
    }

  }     

  winner = getWinner(board, -1, Check.Diagonal);
  if (winner != Piece.Empty) {
    return winner;
  }     

  // Check diagonal     
  winner = getWinner(board, -1, Check.ReverseDiagonal);
  if (winner != Piece.Empty) {
    return winner;
  } 

  return Piece.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time a new piece is placed in the board, you increase the appropriate row, column and (possibly ) diagonal counters by 1. You either have separate counters for the players, or use +1/-1.

Now when you check the board, you only have to check whether any of this counters equals N, which can be done in `O(N)` (2N+2 counters).

Answer (score 2):

What they probably mean is that as you place pieces, you update the sums for each array that the piece contribute to.  That is, the corresponding row and column.  If it's on the diagonal, then you update that too.

In terms of updating, you would add 1 if it is red, and subtract 1 if it is blue.  If your counts begin at 0, then if the value reaches -3 or 3 you have a winner.

Comment: By the way, you only have to check the 2 (or 3) counters that you update as the player plays their piece...  Not all of them.

Comment: Oh, and we all forgot to realise that the centre piece is on both diagonals! =)